# How to cache whole web page?

Tags: html

Is there any method to cache an entire  web page so that when i request for same url again in does not load content from server?

No problem if it does not update contents, and i don't wish to use websql/indexDB etc.

And even i didn't found Manifest File much useful.

Scenario:

Let consider that my website had 3 pages:

page1.html
page2.html
page3.html

I can visit to any of these pages from any pages.

Suppose if i am in page1.html-> i click a link and go to page2.html. Now if i click a link from page2.html to goto page1.html the hole page should not load from server rather it should be capture during first visit and same thing will be displayed when i revisit the url.

My pages can be extends to any number.

Is it possible in any of the way?

Comment: would downloading these pages for offline viewing be acceptable? something like httrack would do that

Comment: Would setting up a dedicated server on your network to handle all web requests be to extravagant? if not I would suggest building a cache server to server your webpages

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to do what you are trying to do simply by using Cache-Control HTTP headers.  See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers#http-cache-headers).